# Why is the SQL query throwing an error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

code:

```
string qr = @"select 'TheCode','CodeDesc' from [dbo].[Table1] as \""Table1\"" order by 'CodeDesc'";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qr, conn);

        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) // Incorrect syntax near '\'.
    {
        string error = ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

I keep getting an error in this line: `cmd.ExecuteReader();`

Error:

```
Incorrect syntax near '\'.
```

How can I resolve the error.

Comment: Can you please put your error's message in the question?

Comment: It is in the code but I can add it in the question too if it's not clear.

Comment: By the way, do you know that SqlCommand and SqlDataReader are also IDisposable like the SqlConnection and you should surround them with the using clause ?

Comment: @DDavid Yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added @ at the beginning of the command string so it will be somthing like that :

```
select distinct 'TheCode','CodeDesc' from [dbo].[Table1] as \""Table1\"" 
order by 'CodeDesc'";
```

So  remove `\""` and `\""` from the command string. You also wrapped the column names by `'` that should be removed

```
string strQryDDL = @"select distinct TheCode,CodeDesc from [dbo].[Table1] as t 
order by CodeDesc";
```

You did not use the alias so you can remove it,

```
string strQryDDL = @"select distinct TheCode,CodeDesc from [dbo].[Table1] 
order by CodeDesc";
```

Comment: Now I get this error: `Invalid object name 'dbo.Table1'.`

Comment: Actually is there any sense in giving the table an alias in this case ?

Comment: do you have `table1` in your database?

Comment: Sorry was using the wrong Db. I get this error now: `A constant expression was encountered in the ORDER BY list, position 1.`

Comment: Thank you. +1 for you. I was able to populate the DropDownList,.

Answer (score 1):

When using the "@" symbol in c# strings, you use don't escape quotes with a slash, you use two in a row like: ""
Your other problem is the single quotes, remove them all, you do not surround field names with quotes, just literal text.